# Calculating run down dates using only percentages using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have a table with information on resources, basics are:

```
ID    Total    Start        End          Used
----------------------------------------------
1     350      01-01-2012   31-12-2012   80.6%
2     250      01-01-2012   31-12-2012   51.5%
3     3500     01-01-2012   31-07-2013   12.5%
4     350      01-01-2012   31-10-2012   91.0%
```

Columns are:

- `Total` -- Total number of the resource (Being currency, time, paper etc).
- `Start` -- Start date of resource
- `End` -- End date of resource
- `Used` -- Percentage of the resource used to date

I have to try to work out (or estimate) when the resource will run out at the rate used so far.

I've tried several different ways using the percentage used and the percentage but nothing makes sense, I'm pretty sure there's a simple way to do this that's staring me in the face but I can't find it.

My ideal output would be in text below but I will probably format in the application:

```
You have used X% of your [resource name] in Y% of the time allotted, 
at this rate the resource will run down around [Run Down Date].
```

Can anyone work out how this can be calculated?

[SQL Fiddle to play with](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b212/1)

**Edit:**

To try and make the problem clearer, I'll explain how I would calculate a single date:

For the first line (ID = 1).

```
Average % per day = Percentage (80.6) / Days between Start and Today (205)
Average % per day = 0.003931707%

% remaining = Percentage (80.6%)
% remaining = 19.4%

Days remaining = Average % per day (0.003931707%) / % remaining (19.4%)
Days remaining = 49.34243176

Project Run Down = Today + Days Remaining (49.34243176)
Project Run Down = 11/09/2012 (11th Sep)
```

I've tried converting this process into SQL but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Why do you calculate this in DB when it's easier to gather data and perform calculation on client?

Comment: abatishchev - Just because it is easier does not make it right.

Comment: I will be using a scheduling package to email reminders which binds to a view/sp so this needs to be done on the db end, the scheduling package has only very simple tools.

Comment: [Please avoid using tags in question's title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: Title originally contained 'MS-SQL' as many folks don't associate the tag 'sql-server' with the MS product. This was then changed by marc_s to be less helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
declare @res table(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,total int
    ,start date
    ,[end] date
    ,used float )


insert into @res(total, start , [end], used) 
values
    (350, '20120101', '20121231', 0.806)
    ,(250, '20120101', '20121231', 0.515)   


select 
*
,used/DATEDIFF(DAY,start,GETDATE()) as avUsePerDay
,1/(used/DATEDIFF(DAY,start,GETDATE())) as expectedDaysTotal
,DATEADD(day,1/(used/DATEDIFF(DAY,start,GETDATE())),start) as expectedToDie
from @res
```

Comment: This seems very promising, checked two examples and is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That would be...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, [StartDate], GETDATE()) * 100.0 /  DATEDIFF(d, [StartDate], [EndDate]) AS PercentageTimeGone,
       DATEADD(d, (100 - USED) / (Used / DATEDIFF(d, [StartDate], GETDATE())), GETDATE()) AS ProjectedEndingDate
FROM Resources
```

Comment: This returns an incorrect value, see my edit for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What's about

```
select id, total, start, end, datediff(day,start,getdate()) / ( total / 100 )
```

I am not good in calculating, but in numbers it's working.

all the best

Comment: I need to return a date that the resource will become depleted rather than a number.